# sqlite3 python count() query error no such column

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to produce a query on the number of times the product Americano comes up in my database table. My database looks like this:

```
id  product size    milkOptions

1   Americano   Small   WholeMilk

2   Espresso    Large   SemiSkimmed
```

This is the query:

```
conn=sqlite3.connect("system.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
americano = cur.execute("""SELECT COUNT(id) FROM customerOrders WHERE product = Americano""")
```

The error is:

```
americano = cur.execute("""SELECT COUNT(id) FROM customerOrders WHERE product = Americano""")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Americano
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if `product`'s value is `Americano` so you need say `Americano` is a string literal, not just a variable.

Currently you are telling SQL to grab all rows where the `product` column is equal to the `Americano` column.

The following should fix that issue:

```
conn=sqlite3.connect("system.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
americano = cur.execute("""SELECT COUNT(id) FROM customerOrders WHERE product = 'Americano'""")
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, how would I print it. When I print the query it does not print the number of times it appears which should be 1. Instead it returns '<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x091D14E0>'

Comment: `for x in americano: print(x)` or `cur.fetchone()` should do it. I don't remember off hand and you will need to do some error handling.